# iMac - connecting an external monitor to my thunderbold ouput

Tags: imac, thunderbolt

I have a LG HDTV that has many inputs HDMI and one VGA. The HDMI input expects the audio to come with the video and the VGA input has a separate audio mini-jack input and when selected expects the audio to come from this minijack input.

I have an old iMac with a miniDVI port. As this miniDVI port do not carries audio and my intention was to connect it to the TV, I was forced to use a miniDVI to VGA adapter to connect the Mac to the TV's VGA input and a second cable with mini-jacks to carry the audio between the Mac and the TV. It works nicely and I have full HDTV resolution on the TV, coming from the miniDVI.

Now I am about to buy one of these new iMac 27" with a thunderbolt port. My idea is to continue using this TV as a second monitor of this new iMac.

But as I don't know the characteristics of this thunderbolt port, I ask you guys:

1) as far as I read, this Mac thunderbolt output has the same connector as the miniDisplay port plug and works with that cable. If this is true, my best option to connect this new mac to this TV is to use a miniDisplay to HDMI adapter, right? Which one have you test and you can recommend? Apple's?

2) will I have audio?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one of the new Macbook Pros. I know for sure that it is the same style of port as mini display port and that the adapters that are made for mini display port will also work with the thunderbolt port. I was also in the market for an HDMI adapter so I did some research, as of last year (2010 models), mini display port and now thunderbolt carry audio. I have not tested the audio part yet, apple's site had it listed as a feature though.

Comment: thanks. I have bought [this cable](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Apple-DisplayPort-Adapter-cable-Neet®/dp/B002ERBFYM/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1306965884&sr=1-2) from amazon now. Several reviewers telling the cable works with audio for connecting a Thunderbolt or mini displayPort to HDMI!